# Upload product image with product name from xamarin form to web api

Tags: json

i am using entity framework in web API for posting product details of name, image and price from Xamarin form to web API to save product details in API. But i don't know how to save image on web API folder. please anyone guide me how to do that....

Answer (score 0):

```
Umar sir 

below code i am using but i don't know how to save image in web server folder and database.

--------------------
web API call from Xamarin form
---------------------------

var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
string url = "https://example.com/api/Product;
request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36");

//file to base64 string
byte[] b = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(txtImage.Text);
String s = Convert.ToBase64String(b);

tblProduct product= new tblProduct()
{
   ProductName = txtCategoryName.Text,
   Price = txtPrice.Text,
   ProductImage = s
};

var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(url, content).Result;

--------------------
web API code
--------------------
 public HttpResponseMessage Post(tblProduct product)
 {
    HttpResponseMessage response = null;
    using (orderapp_dbEntities entity = new orderapp_dbEntities())
    {
     var img= Convert.FromBase64String(product.ProductImage);

     tblProduct prd = new tblProduct()
    {
      ProductName = product.ProductName,
      Price=product.Price,
      ProductImage = img
    };

     entity.tblProducts.Add(prd);
     entity.SaveChanges();

response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, prd);
return response;
}
}
```